# Bigquery Standard Dialect REGEXP_REPLACE input type

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, gdelt

I am exploring the power of Google Biguery with the GDELT database using this [tutorial](https://blog.gdeltproject.org/google-bigquery-gkg-2-0-sample-queries/) however the sql dialect is in 'legacy' and I would like to use the standard dialect.

In legacy dialect:

```
SELECT
  theme,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Themes,';'), r',.*',"") theme
from [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg]
where DATE>20150302000000 and DATE < 20150304000000 and V2Persons like '%Netanyahu%'
)
group by theme
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 300
```

and when I try to translate into standard dialect:

```
SELECT
  theme,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Themes,';') , r',.*', " ") AS theme
    FROM
      `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg`
    WHERE
      DATE>20150302000000
      AND DATE < 20150304000000
      AND V2Persons LIKE '%Netanyahu%' )
  GROUP BY
    theme
  ORDER BY
    2 DESC
  LIMIT
    300
```

it throws the following error:

```
No matching signature for function REGEXP_REPLACE for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING, STRING, STRING); REGEXP_REPLACE(BYTES, BYTES, BYTES) at [6:5]
```

it seems like I have to cast the result of the SPLIT() operation as a string. How do I do this?

UPDATE: I found a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxNrkjBeHpw) explaining the unnest operation:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(themes,",.*","") AS theme
FROM
  `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`,
  UNNEST( SPLIT(V2Themes,";") ) AS themes
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME >= "2018-08-09 00:00:00"
  AND _PARTITIONTIME < "2018-08-10 00:00:00"
  AND V2Persons LIKE '%Netanyahu%'
GROUP BY
  theme
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
LIMIT
  100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flatten the array first:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(theme , r',.*', " ") AS theme,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
  `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg`,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Themes,';')) AS theme
WHERE
  DATE>20150302000000
  AND DATE < 20150304000000
  AND V2Persons LIKE '%Netanyahu%' 
GROUP BY
  theme
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
LIMIT
  300
```

The legacy SQL equivalent in your question actually has the effect of flattening the array as well, although it's implicit in the GROUP BY on the theme.

Comment: the code does not work "as is". I just copied it in the query editor and get the error: "Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING at [6:10]"

Comment: I edited it and moved the split, which creates the array, to the cross join

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't read closely enough. I was focused on the `V2Themes`, which I was thinking was an array. Thanks for the edit!